# How to use python beautiful soup to get only the level 1 navigableText?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to get the text from this example html code:

```
....
<div style="s1">
    <div style="s2">Here is text 1</div>
    <div style="s3">Here is text 2</div>
Here is text 3 and this is what I want.
</div>
....
```

Text 1 and text 2 is at the same level 2 and the text 3 is at the upper level 1. I only want to get the text 3 and used this:

```
for anchor in tbody.findAll('div', style="s1"):
    review=anchor.text
    print review
```

But these code get me all the text 1,2,3. How do I only get the first level text 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
for anchor in tbody.findAll('div', style="s1"):
    text = ''.join([x for x in anchor.contents if isinstance(x, bs4.element.NavigableString)])
```

works.  Just know that you'll also get the line breaks in there, so `.strip()`ing might be necessary.

For example:

```
for anchor in tbody.findAll('div', style="s1"):
    text = ''.join([x for x in anchor.contents if isinstance(x, bs4.element.NavigableString)])
    print([text])
    print([text.strip()])
```

Prints

```
[u'\n\n\nHere is text 3 and this is what I want.\n']
[u'Here is text 3 and this is what I want.']
```

(I put them in lists so you could see the newlines.)

Comment: I ran the code and it shows that bs4 is not defined. I am using python2.7.4 and I do have the line "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" on top. How do I modified your "bs4.element.NavigableString" part?

Comment: Just add `import bs4` in your imports.  Or, add `from bs4.element import NavigableString` and change the `bs4.element.NavigableString` parts of the code I listed to simply `NavigableString`.  Either one works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is

```
tbody.findAll('div', style="s1")[0].string
```

or the index of whichever div.s1 you're looking for.