# How to scrape between span tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape text using python+beautifulsoup. I type in code such as:

```
soup.find_all("span")[0]
```

This gets me:

```
<span style="margin-right: 0.9em">TEXT1 <span style="color:
#111111; margin-left: 0.2em">TEXT2 </span>TEXT3 </span>
```

This is great. But the problem is that I want to extract `TEXT1`, `TEXT2`, and `TEXT3` separately.

I don't know how to do this. If I do:

soup.find_all("span")[0].find_all("span"), I only get

```
<span style="color:
#111111; margin-left: 0.2em">TEXT2 </span>
```

I think that this is because this particular one contains both `<span>` and `</span>`. How do I pick out `TEXT1`, `TEXT2`, and `TEXT3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little bit of formatting, we can see what kind of structure you have:

```
<span style="margin-right: 0.9em">
    TEXT1 
    <span style="color:#111111; margin-left: 0.2em">
        TEXT2 
    </span>
    TEXT3
</span>
```

So, unfortunately, we can't use an approach [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180783/how-to-use-python-beautiful-soup-to-get-only-the-level-1-navigabletext/17180832#17180832) since we want to access the `NavigableText` elements at multiple depths.

One way to do this is to create a function that recursively checks the children of some given element (called `context` in the following function), and if they're `NavigableText` elements, gather them up and return them.

Consider:

```
from bs4.element import NavigableString, Tag

def extractNavigableStrings(context):
    strings = []
    for e in context.children:
        if isinstance(e, NavigableString):
            strings.append(e)
        if isinstance(e, Tag):
            strings.extend(extractNavigableStrings(e))
    return strings
```

Which we can run on your input:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString, Tag

def extractNavigableStrings(context):
    strings = []
    for e in context.children:
        if isinstance(e, NavigableString):
            strings.append(e)
        if isinstance(e, Tag):
            strings.extend(extractNavigableStrings(e))
    return strings

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<span style="margin-right: 0.9em">TEXT1 <span style="color: #111111; margin-left: 0.2em">TEXT2 </span>TEXT3 </span>''')

print(extractNavigableStrings(soup))
```

And the `print` function displays our list of `NavigableStrings`

```
[u'TEXT1 ', u'TEXT2 ', u'TEXT3 ']
```

Note that the elements of the returned list are not python strings, they `NavigableString` elements -- printing them is fine, but if you want to get the string content, you will want `unicode(<element>)`.  For example:

```
nss = extractNavigableStrings(soup)
strings = [unicode(ns.string) for ns in nss]
print strings  # [u'TEXT1 ', u'TEXT2 ', u'TEXT3 ']

for s in strings: print type(s), s
# <type 'unicode'> TEXT1
# <type 'unicode'> TEXT2
# <type 'unicode'> TEXT3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet that gets the job done using the text property.

```
In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup('<span style="margin-right: 0.9em">TEXT1 <span style="color:#111111; margin-left: 0.2em">TEXT2 </span>TEXT3 </span>')
   ...:

In [4]: soup
Out[4]: <html><body><span style="margin-right: 0.9em">TEXT1 <span style="color:#111111; margin-left: 0.2em">TEXT2 </span>TEXT3 </span></body></html>

In [5]: soup.text
Out[5]: u'TEXT1 TEXT2 TEXT3 '
```

You can strip and split the output as well.

```
In [7]: soup.text.strip().split()
Out[7]: [u'TEXT1', u'TEXT2', u'TEXT3']
```

Comment: And if `TEXTn` contains spaces?  How can you distinguish between the end of `TEXTi` and the start of `TEXTj`?

Comment: This works great. The only thing I'll have to figure out is how to deal with situations where TEXT2 is more than 1 word. In other words, it contains a space in the middle of the string.

Comment: @bill999 Yes, as jedwards pointed out this won't work in that case.

Comment: @bill999, any way thank you for quick solution for simple cases.